# Software to bulk/batch convert thousands of PNG image files to JPG without changing timestamps (Windows)

Tags: windows, gratis, images, image-processing

I'm looking for gratis Windows software to bulk/batch convert thousands of PNG image files to JPG.  The big requirement is that ***both*** the created and modified timestamps of the files must be maintained.

The software can be GUI or CLI.  Either (or both) is fine.

A bonus will be the functionality to recursively traverse directories (folders) to process all PNG files within them.

Another bonus will be to allow the user to set the compression level for the JPG image output files.

Comment: Something ding this job excellently is… aw, Windows. Not sure if it exists for that niche system… #D What I use is a simple shell script: `for img in *.png; do mogrify -format jpg $img; touch -r $img ${img%%.png).jpg; done`. Mogrify is part of ImageMagick – and my script is using Bash. As for your bonus: easy enough to accomplish with looping over `find . -type d`, and exit the loop when nothing is found anymore. Could most likely be done in Cygwin…

Comment: @Izzy I think your New Year's Resolution needs to be moving me 100% to Linux. :)

Comment: Oh, I got caught… Pledging guilty and adopting that resolution. It's a good one :) // I threw out Windows through my windows around 1995 (my last one was 3.11) in favor of a "real OS". Never regretted that :D

Comment: @Izzy Sounds good.  We'll create a chat for it, or more likely talk on another platform (any ideas?).  I've wanted to completely switch to Linux for well over a decade, but I'm so efficient on Windows that it's challenging to leave so much knowledge & experience behind.  Plus, I use over 100 different Windows utilities (probably 20-25 of them regularly), and finding similar tools for Linux that are reliable seems like a time-consuming task.  The good news is that I've been working on switching for so long that 90% of my main non-utility applications are now intentionally cross-platform.

Comment: Yes, a chat is much better suited for that purpose. Feel free to open a room and invite me (no promises on fast or real-time reactions, though). I'm also permanently in our official room, and if you prefer you can also reach me via XMPP or Threema (the latter would also offer voice). Jitsi and BBB would also be options… ;)

Comment: So bulk/batch convert for any image format to another one is defenetly not a problem and defenetly much easier to use that the Linux solution, but what is meaned by timestamps exactly?

Comment: @convert Every file in Windows has 3 timestamps: time/date created, time/date modified, and time/date accessed.  Since the 'accessed' timestamp is changed every time you access the file, it is not important for this recommendation request.  That leaves us with the 'created' and 'modified' timestamps, which I do not want to be changed.

Comment: But aren´t that timestamps created automaticaly with the coresponding file?

Comment: I am not so much familiar with Linux, as I am not using it myself, but the solution  
Izzy would not work for that timestamps as Linux uses diferent timestamps then Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look at this software(freeware). It has feature for batch conversion of files and many others. (I also use this software - easy, small, light on resources)

https://www.irfanview.com/

Under the File Menu -> Batch Conversion/Rename, you can select the "Use advanced options" check box and then click "Advanced" to open the advanced option window.  In the lower right you will find the option to preserve the "Original date/time"

[image: Advanced options to preserve file time stamps]

When you select jpeg as the output format and select options, you will be able to set the compression level as well as other options

[image: jpeg compression options]

Comment: Does this satisfy the requirement that bot the created and modified timestamps of the files must be maintained?